# Random sound onclick button android assets

Tags: android, button, audio, random, assets

I want to play random sounds from assets/ folder in my project.
What's wrong with that code? Help me please

Here's my code:

```
MediaPlayer player;
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;
private String[] filelist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
    AssetManager aMan = this.getAssets();
    try {
        filelist = aMan.list("mysounds/");

        // OR
        // filelist = aMan.list("/");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        {
        }
        bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(filelist.length);

                try {
                    String mediaFile = filelist[randomInt];
                    descriptor = getAssets().openFd(mediaFile);
                    player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                            descriptor.getStartOffset(),
                            descriptor.getLength());
                    descriptor.close();
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

After click on the button nothing sound is playing. Help me!
No errors displays.

Comment: just checking the basics:  are you sure your media volume is turned up?  have you debugged to make sure the filelist contains valid filenames?

Comment: Yes. I've got two .mp3 files in my assets folder also i tried to make folder /mysounds and add there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Mediaplayer constructor:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(Context context, Uri uri);
uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/mysounds/music.mp3");
```

Comment: Yes but i want to play randomly music on click